# Lua behaves funny with string.match

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

Here is a very simple code that didn't work as expected :

```lua
function convert(str)
  local _,name = string.match(str, [[<a href=(.*)>(%w+)</a>]])
  return name
end

print(convert("<a href=\"/organization/1/\">A</a>"))

print(convert("<a href=\"/organization/2/\">B</a>"))

print(convert("<a href=\"/organization/3/\">C</a>"))
```

I expected :

```
A
B
C
```

And got :

```
A
nil 
nil
```

Can somebody explain me how Lua is working in this case ?

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ZM1zKW. What is the Lua version?

Comment: Version is 5.3 and IDE is Zerobrane.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, got it...

I put sample values for StackOverflow. Real values had spaces. I transformed the function to

```lua
function convert(str)
  local _,name = string.match(str, [[<a href=(.*)>(.*)</a>]])
  return name
end
```